# Automatically mount a pendrive to /media in Raspberry Pi

Tags: boot, usb, mount, raspberrypi

Whenever I insert a USB drive in any of the USB ports of my Raspberry Pi, the drive automatically gets mounted at `/media/root/`.

I have an utility that needs the drive to be mounted to `/media`.

Every time I have to unmount the drive from `/media/root/` and mount it at `/media`.

Moreover, the utility autoruns to copy some files from the USB drive as soon as it is inserted.

How can I make the drive mount automatically to `/media` by default?

Comment: If you occupy /media with your pendrive, how are you going to mount all the other stuff?

Comment: Which Ubuntu edition are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are sure that `/media` is the right place to mount your pen-drive.

You can use the method described [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-mount-a-usb-flash-disk-on-the-raspberry-pi/)

**Auto Mount**

If you want your USB drive to be mounted when the system starts you can edit the fstab file :

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Then add the following line at the end :

```
UUID=18A9-9943 /media/usb vfat auto,nofail,noatime,users,rw,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

> The “nofail” option allows the boot process to proceed if the drive is
>   not plugged in. The “noatime” option stops the file access time being
>   updated every time a file is read from the USB stick. This helps
>   improve performance.

**Make sure you set the correct UUID (i.e. the UUID of your pen-drive).**

Use CTRL-X followed by Y to save and exit the nano editor.

Comment: @Debopam - if my answer solved your question please accept it